# Distinguish between not set at all AND null?

Tags: php, null

```
$record['field'] = null;

if (isset($record['field']) || is_null($record['field'])) {
  // When $record['field'] is set and not null, OR, when $record['field'] = null
  // Basically, when $record['field'] is defined as $record['field'] = whatever, even null.
} else {
  // When $record['field'] is not defined at all, not even null
}
```

My intention is to check if `$record['field']` is defined at all, even `null`.

However every time `$record['field']` is not set at all (e.g. comment out $record['field'] = null;), it gives me this error:

```
Undefined index: field
```

In case anyone would ask, this is for when NULL values become meaningful, such as in a SQL query assigning a NULL value to a timestamp column would make MySQL update it with the current timestamp.

Any way I can do this?

Comment: Note that the "undefined index" is a Notice, not an Error, you can choose to ignore it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you have here is not just a variable but an associative array, you can use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) to check that the array contains a field with that name, regardless of its value.